# Why aren't my profiles being displayed in equal location?

Tags: html, css

So I have a page that displays the matches a user has matched with, other users. In the display page, the profiles are being displayed unevenly. Each profile card is sometimes a different size and being displayed in a slightly different uneven location. How can I get them to all be the same size and be displayed evenly? Is it due to the photo size?

**matches.html**

```
    {% extends "dating_app/base.html" %}

{% load bootstrap4 %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
{% block head %}
<head>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>


</head>

{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<br>
<title>Your Matches</title>



<div class="container">


    <h5>Your Matches:</h5>
    {% for item in match %}
        <div class="container">    
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">  <h4 style="color:#CB2603  "   >My Profile</h4></div>
                       <div class="panel-body">
                      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                       <img alt="User Pic" src="{{  item.photo.url   }}" width="500"  id="profile-image1" class="img-circle img-responsive"> 


                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-8" >
                          <div class="container" >
                            <h2>{{ item.username }}</h2>



                          </div>
                           <hr>
                          <ul class="container details" >
                            <h3   >About me</h3>
                                <p><span  style="width:50px;margin:50px"></span>{{ item.description }}</p>

                          </ul>
                          <hr>

                        <a href="{% url 'dating_app:message' item.id %}">Start messaging {{item.username}} now!</a>
                      </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    {% endfor %}


</div>


{% endblock content %}
```

**base.html**

```
{% load bootstrap4 %}
{% load static %}

{% load unread_messages_counter %}

<!-- Navbar is located in this file -->


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    {% block head %}
    <title>Base</title>
    {% endblock %}
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>





    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="{% static  'css/notification.css' %}" type="text/css" class = "notification"/>
    <style>
    <!-- Add this tag -->
    {% block styles %}

    {% endblock %}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Navigation -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-expand-md">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class= 'navbar-brand'  href="{% url 'dating_app:home' %}"><img src="{% static 'images/cupids_corner_logo.jpg' %}"><h5 style="color:red"></h5> </a>
        <button class= "navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
        data-target="#navbarResponsive">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div  class="collapse navbar-collapse"  >
          <ul class ="navbar-nav ml-auto" >


            {% if user.is_authenticated %}


                {% unread_messages request.user as user_unread_messages %}
                {% if user_unread_messages > 0 %}


                    <li class="nav-item"  >
                        <a class=  "notification" style="color:brown" href="{% url 'dating_app:conversations' user.id %}" type="text/css" > 
                        <span>Inbox</span>
                        <span class="badge">{% unread_messages request.user %}</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                {% else %}

                    <li class="nav-item">

                        <a style="color:brown"  href="{% url 'dating_app:conversations' user.id %}">    
                            <span>Inbox</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a style="color:brown"  href="{% url 'dating_app:view_matches' user.id %}">Matches</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a style="color:brown"  href="{% url 'dating_app:mingle' %}">Mingle</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a style="color:brown" href="{% url 'dating_app:profile' user.id %}">My Profile</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a style="color:brown" href="{% url 'dating_app:logout' %}">log out</a>
                </li>
            {% else %}

                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a style="color:brown" href="{% url 'dating_app:login' %}">login</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a style="color:brown" href="{% url 'dating_app:register' %}">register</a>
                </li>

            {% endif %}
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    </nav>

<!-- HEADER END -->


<!--Below is individual page will html will be rendered -->

{% block content %}

{% endblock %}

<hr class="my-4">

<!--Connect -->
<div class="container-fluid padding">
<div class="row text-center padding">
     <div class="col-12">
        <h2>Connect</h2>
     </div>
     <div class="col-12 social padding">
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
        <a href="http://www.twitter.com/"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
        <a href="http://www.instagram.com/"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
        <a href="http://www.google.com/"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- FOOTER AREA BEGINS BELOW-->

<footer>
    <div class="container-fluid padding">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="{% static 'images/cupids_corner_logo.jpg' %}">
            <hr class="light">
            <p>703-309-9572</p>
            <p>rezazandirz@gmail.com</p>
            <p>100 Street Name</p>
            <p>City, State, 000</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <hr class="light">
            <h5>Our hours</h5>
            <hr class="light">
            <p>Monday: 9am-5pm</p>
            <p>Saturday: 10am-4pm</p>
            <p>Sunday: closed(like Chick-fil-A)</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <hr class="light">
            <h5>Our satellite offices</h5>
            <hr class="light">
            <p>City, State, 00000</p>
            <p>City, State, 00000</p>
            <p>City, State, 00000</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <hr class="light-100">
            <h5>&copy;CupidsCorner.com</h5>
        </div>


</footer>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
      ================================================== -->
      <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->

      <script src="../../assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**_reboot.scss**

```
    *::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box; // 1
}

html {
  font-family: sans-serif; // 2
  line-height: 1.15; // 3
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; // 4
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; // 4
  -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar; // 5
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); // 6
}

// IE10+ doesn't honor `<meta name="viewport">` in some cases.
@at-root {
  @-ms-viewport {
    width: device-width;
  }
}

// stylelint-disable selector-list-comma-newline-after
// Shim for "new" HTML5 structural elements to display correctly (IE10, older browsers)
article, aside, dialog, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, nav, section {
  display: block;
}
// stylelint-enable selector-list-comma-newline-after

// Body
//
// 1. Remove the margin in all browsers.
// 2. As a best practice, apply a default `background-color`.
// 3. Set an explicit initial text-align value so that we can later use the
//    the `inherit` value on things like `<th>` elements.

body {
  margin: 0; // 1
  font-family: $font-family-base;
  font-size: $font-size-base;
  font-weight: $font-weight-base;
  line-height: $line-height-base;
  color: $body-color;
  text-align: left; // 3
  background-color: $body-bg; // 2
}

// Suppress the focus outline on elements that cannot be accessed via keyboard.
// This prevents an unwanted focus outline from appearing around elements that
// might still respond to pointer events.
//
// Credit: https://github.com/suitcss/base
[tabindex="-1"]:focus {
  outline: 0 !important;
}


// Content grouping
//
// 1. Add the correct box sizing in Firefox.
// 2. Show the overflow in Edge and IE.

hr {
  box-sizing: content-box; // 1
  height: 0; // 1
  overflow: visible; // 2
}


//
// Typography
//

// Remove top margins from headings
//
// By default, `<h1>`-`<h6>` all receive top and bottom margins. We nuke the top
// margin for easier control within type scales as it avoids margin collapsing.
// stylelint-disable selector-list-comma-newline-after
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: $headings-margin-bottom;
}
// stylelint-enable selector-list-comma-newline-after

// Reset margins on paragraphs
//
// Similarly, the top margin on `<p>`s get reset. However, we also reset the
// bottom margin to use `rem` units instead of `em`.
p {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: $paragraph-margin-bottom;
}

// Abbreviations
//
// 1. Remove the bottom border in Firefox 39-.
// 2. Add the correct text decoration in Chrome, Edge, IE, Opera, and Safari.
// 3. Add explicit cursor to indicate changed behavior.
// 4. Duplicate behavior to the data-* attribute for our tooltip plugin

abbr[title],
abbr[data-original-title] { // 4
  text-decoration: underline; // 2
  text-decoration: underline dotted; // 2
  cursor: help; // 3
  border-bottom: 0; // 1
}

address {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: inherit;
}

ol,
ul,
dl {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

ol ol,
ul ul,
ol ul,
ul ol {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

dt {
  font-weight: $dt-font-weight;
}

dd {
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  margin-left: 0; // Undo browser default
}

blockquote {
  margin: 0 0 1rem;
}

dfn {
  font-style: italic; // Add the correct font style in Android 4.3-
}

// stylelint-disable font-weight-notation
b,
strong {
  font-weight: bolder; // Add the correct font weight in Chrome, Edge, and Safari
}
// stylelint-enable font-weight-notation

small {
  font-size: 80%; // Add the correct font size in all browsers
}

//
// Prevent `sub` and `sup` elements from affecting the line height in
// all browsers.
//

sub,
sup {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

sub { bottom: -.25em; }
sup { top: -.5em; }


//
// Links
//

a {
  color: $link-color;
  text-decoration: $link-decoration;
  background-color: transparent; // Remove the gray background on active links in IE 10.
  -webkit-text-decoration-skip: objects; // Remove gaps in links underline in iOS 8+ and Safari 8+.

  @include hover {
    color: $link-hover-color;
    text-decoration: $link-hover-decoration;
  }
}

// And undo these styles for placeholder links/named anchors (without href)
// which have not been made explicitly keyboard-focusable (without tabindex).
// It would be more straightforward to just use a[href] in previous block, but that
// causes specificity issues in many other styles that are too complex to fix.
// See https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/19402

a:not([href]):not([tabindex]) {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;

  @include hover-focus {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  &:focus {
    outline: 0;
  }
}


//
// Code
//

// stylelint-disable font-family-no-duplicate-names
pre,
code,
kbd,
samp {
  font-family: monospace, monospace; // Correct the inheritance and scaling of font size in all browsers.
  font-size: 1em; // Correct the odd `em` font sizing in all browsers.
}
// stylelint-enable font-family-no-duplicate-names

pre {
  // Remove browser default top margin
  margin-top: 0;
  // Reset browser default of `1em` to use `rem`s
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  // Don't allow content to break outside
  overflow: auto;
  // We have @viewport set which causes scrollbars to overlap content in IE11 and Edge, so
  // we force a non-overlapping, non-auto-hiding scrollbar to counteract.
  -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
}


//
// Figures
//

figure {
  // Apply a consistent margin strategy (matches our type styles).
  margin: 0 0 1rem;
}


//
// Images and content
//

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-style: none; // Remove the border on images inside links in IE 10-.
}

svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden; // Hide the overflow in IE
}


//
// Tables
//

table {
  border-collapse: collapse; // Prevent double borders
}

caption {
  padding-top: $table-cell-padding;
  padding-bottom: $table-cell-padding;
  color: $text-muted;
  text-align: left;
  caption-side: bottom;
}

th {
  // Matches default `<td>` alignment by inheriting from the `<body>`, or the
  // closest parent with a set `text-align`.
  text-align: inherit;
}


//
// Forms
//

label {
  // Allow labels to use `margin` for spacing.
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
}

// Remove the default `border-radius` that macOS Chrome adds.
//
// Details at https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/24093
button {
  border-radius: 0;
}

// Work around a Firefox/IE bug where the transparent `button` background
// results in a loss of the default `button` focus styles.
//
// Credit: https://github.com/suitcss/base/
button:focus {
  outline: 1px dotted;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
}

input,
button,
select,
optgroup,
textarea {
  margin: 0; // Remove the margin in Firefox and Safari
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
}

button,
input {
  overflow: visible; // Show the overflow in Edge
}

button,
select {
  text-transform: none; // Remove the inheritance of text transform in Firefox
}

// 1. Prevent a WebKit bug where (2) destroys native `audio` and `video`
//    controls in Android 4.
// 2. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
button,
html [type="button"], // 1
[type="reset"],
[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button; // 2
}

// Remove inner border and padding from Firefox, but don't restore the outline like Normalize.
button::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0;
  border-style: none;
}

input[type="radio"],
input[type="checkbox"] {
  box-sizing: border-box; // 1. Add the correct box sizing in IE 10-
  padding: 0; // 2. Remove the padding in IE 10-
}


input[type="date"],
input[type="time"],
input[type="datetime-local"],
input[type="month"] {
  // Remove the default appearance of temporal inputs to avoid a Mobile Safari
  // bug where setting a custom line-height prevents text from being vertically
  // centered within the input.
  // See https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=139848
  // and https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11266
  -webkit-appearance: listbox;
}

textarea {
  overflow: auto; // Remove the default vertical scrollbar in IE.
  // Textareas should really only resize vertically so they don't break their (horizontal) containers.
  resize: vertical;
}

fieldset {
  // Browsers set a default `min-width: min-content;` on fieldsets,
  // unlike e.g. `<div>`s, which have `min-width: 0;` by default.
  // So we reset that to ensure fieldsets behave more like a standard block element.
  // See https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12359
  // and https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/#the-fieldset-and-legend-elements
  min-width: 0;
  // Reset the default outline behavior of fieldsets so they don't affect page layout.
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

// 1. Correct the text wrapping in Edge and IE.
// 2. Correct the color inheritance from `fieldset` elements in IE.
legend {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%; // 1
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: inherit;
  color: inherit; // 2
  white-space: normal; // 1
}

progress {
  vertical-align: baseline; // Add the correct vertical alignment in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera.
}

// Correct the cursor style of increment and decrement buttons in Chrome.
[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  height: auto;
}

[type="search"] {
  // This overrides the extra rounded corners on search inputs in iOS so that our
  // `.form-control` class can properly style them. Note that this cannot simply
  // be added to `.form-control` as it's not specific enough. For details, see
  // https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11586.
  outline-offset: -2px; // 2. Correct the outline style in Safari.
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

//
// Remove the inner padding and cancel buttons in Chrome and Safari on macOS.
//

[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

//
// 1. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
// 2. Change font properties to `inherit` in Safari.
//

::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  font: inherit; // 2
  -webkit-appearance: button; // 1
}

//
// Correct element displays
//

output {
  display: inline-block;
}

summary {
  display: list-item; // Add the correct display in all browsers
  cursor: pointer;
}

template {
  display: none; // Add the correct display in IE
}

// Always hide an element with the `hidden` HTML attribute (from PureCSS).
// Needed for proper display in IE 10-.
[hidden] {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: What's with the {% %} lines? Please include the generated HTML rather than the pre-generated/pre-compiled stuff. Also, if you have some CSS, please include the relevant parts so that we have a [mcve] to work with.

Comment: what do you mean what's with the {% %} lines? How do I show the generated html? Still new to the front end work.

Comment: `{% %}` and `{{ }}` are not valid HTML, so I'm guessing you're working with something like PHP where you can mix PHP and HTML markup and then 'compile' or 'build' the page. The outputted HTML will be what is shown in the browser or when you press CTRL+U from the webpage and show the "source".

Comment: I'm working with python and django. Ok, let me try to include that.

Comment: @TylerH So for sources I have two files, _reboot.scss and index. Should I copy paste that code here? Is that your saying? Or should I take a screen shot of the what the site actually displays on the browser?

Comment: Definitely not a screenshot. For starters, we can try leaving the HTML in your question as-is. Add the styles from your _reboot.scss file to the question, but only the styles that apply to the HTML you're having trouble with. (E.g. if you're having an issue with positioning elements on a page, you should leave out stuff like "color" or "font-weight", etc.)

Comment: @TylerH I think I identified the problem. I have bootstrap4 on my base.html and bootstrap3 on matches.html because this code I got is in bootstrap 3. So I have scripts for bootstrap4 on my base.html and scripts for bootstrap3 on my matches.html. How do I convert to bootstrap4? Also, I have no idea what part of _reboot.scss deals with matches.html, I'm a total noob on the FE side, so I just pasted it all. But I think it has more to do with the bootstrap being 3 and not 4.

Comment: Since you are now asking a different question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62457401/how-can-i-convert-this-piece-of-code-from-bootstrap-3-to-4. this can be deleted